# Woocommerce product images broken link

Tags: image, woocommerce

Suddenly my Wordpress files went missing from the server.I restored the files from a backup i have taken earlier. Now, i see that after restoring the backup, the product images don't appear on the website and just saw a broken link. Please help me, what could have gone wrong.